# How to scrape canvas chart data points using Octoparse

Tags: canvas, highcharts, floating-point, axis

[image]

How do I scrape floating data values and Date while hovering over chart using Octoparse?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post a sample working example where we can see the issue.

Comment: You have used highcharts tag, but the problem doesn't seem to be about a chart - rather about using the Octopars. If you'll have problems with Highcharts then please provide a demo with hard-coded, exemplary data.